# Sql Server Management Studio 2008 making the most of the Table designer

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2008

Does anyone have any good articles or even more preferable screencasts to using the table designer for SSMS 2008 to get the most out of it?

To often I end up trying to fumble through it and just end up googling the sql script to do specifically what I'm trying to accomplish with keys or indexes etc and just end up repeating the process over again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best article I ended up finding on this was [Creating databases using SQL Server Management Studio Express byHerleson Paiva Pontes](http://www.mrbool.com/articles/viewcomp.asp?comp=4672)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know of any videos specifically targetted at the Table Designer in SSMS 2008, but this site here has a bunch of quite useful videos on various SQL Server topics - also on SSMS in particular:

http://www.sqlservervideos.com/browse/tag/ssms/

Hope that helps a bit

Marc